# elasticsearch Query today's ID did not appear before

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Query out the data of the specified conditions, and then according inside the field id is excluded in the data of specified time range.
Business background: Every time a user request, record device Id and time, I need to query the new user (that is, today's device id does not appear in record of the before).

SQL:`

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM logstash*
WHERE 
    request_act = 'xxx'
    and request_domain = 'xxx' 
    and request_device = 'xxx'
    and request_appname = 'xxx'
    and request_begints  >= 1494604800
    and request_begints  < 1494691200
and request_id not in (
    select 
        distinct request_id 
    from logstash*
    where request_act = 'xxx'
    and request_domain = 'xxx'
    and request_device = 'xxx'
    and request_appname = 'xxx' 
    and request_begints  < 1494604800
)
```

`

[image: SQL]

Please tell me how to write this DSL request?

Thanks, Best regards！

Answer (score 0):

I got this conclusion as I understood

The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only different values.

First of all inner query executed and get unique id's of request_id then outer query will be executed and it fetch all id's of request_id,

but you check condition for **NOT IN**, But all different values of the inner query are part of all results.

so you can not get results.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, NOT IN condition is "and request_begints  < 1494604800", this is date < today.

Comment: TRY this:       SELECT * FROM logstash WHERE 
    request_act = 'xxx'
    and request_domain = 'xxx' 
    and request_device = 'xxx'
    and request_appname = 'xxx' HAVING request_begints BETWEEN '1494604800' AND '1494691200'

Comment: This is not the data I want. This is just the day of the data, I need is to distinct the same day the new device ID, the device ID did not appear in the past.